# Make delete button procedurally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML:

```
<button id='pusher'>pusher</button>

<ul id="sortable">
    <li>things here</li>
</ul>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$(".del").click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});


$("#pusher").click(function(e) {
    var text = "test";
    var lix = $("<li class='uix' />").text(text);
    lix.append($('<button class="del">xx</button>'));
    lix.appendTo($("#sortable"));
});
```

I'm trying to make the pusher button make new `<li>` elements with a delete button inside, then when delete button is pressed it deletes its `<li>` element...

But it is not deleting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get an error?  Does Firebug tell you anything?

Comment: Firebug returns no error.  Just the xx buttons have no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".del").click(function(e) {
```

This only binds to `.del` elements that exist when it's ran.  You want to use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

```
$(".del").live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

This will bind the event to the element, no matter when it was added.

EDIT: It seems `.live` is deprecated, try using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

```
$(document).on('click', '.del', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Again. `live` is depricated. Refer to api.jquery.com/on instead.

Comment: Actually, unless forced to use an old (pre 1.7) version of jQuery, you want to use .on() instead of .live() ;)

Comment: Guy - What is the replacement?

Comment: @David19801 Use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) if using jQuery <1.4.3.  Use [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) if using jQuery >= 1.4.3 and < 1.7.  Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for jQuery >= 1.7.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your problem is that the elements don't exist at the time you use `.click` to bind the handler. You could use `.live`, but a better solution is to attach the handler dynamically since you control the element:

```
function deleteClicked(e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
}

$(".del").click(deleteClicked);


$("#pusher").click(function(e) {
    var text = "test";
    var lix = $("<li>").addClass('uix').text(text);
    lix.append($('<button>').addClass('del').text('xx').click(deleteClicked));
    lix.appendTo($("#sortable"));
});
```

Comment: @Guy: I know, that's why I didn't use it ;) I wouldn't want to give misinformation about `on`, which I have no clue how to use. Tell Rocket that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery `on` || `live` event binding which will attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

jQuery 1.7+

```
$(document).on('click', '.del', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

jQuery 1.3+

```
$('.del').live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: @Rocket Yeah indeed it's a bit weird.